# Child To Parent Trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to update Phone field of Account as Per Its First Contact . please Help me achieve this.

```
trigger ContactToAccount on Contact (After update) {

List <Account> AccList = new List <Account>();
    
for(contact con:trigger.new){
    for(Account Ac :[select id,LastName,Phone from contact where AccountId = :Ac.id]){
        
        Ac.Phone = con.Phone ;
        //Ac.Email = con.Email__c ;
        
        Acclist.add(Ac);
    }
 } update AccList ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at Process Builder first. You can build this kind of update rather easily.

As far as the trigger goes, you should query the parents, then update as appropriate. A full version would look like:

```
trigger contactTrigger on Contact(after insert, after update) {
    Contact[] scope = new Contact[0];
    Map<Id, Account> parents = new Map<Id, Account>();
    Map<Id, Account> updates = new Map<Id, Account>();
    // Find changed contacts
    for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
        Contact oldRecord = Trigger.oldMap.get(record.Id);
        if(record.AccountId != null && oldRecord.Phone != record.Phone) {
            parents.put(record.AccountId, null);
            scope.add(record);
        }
    }
    // Query parents
    parents.putAll([SELECT Phone FROM Account WHERE Id = :parents.keySet()]);
    // Update parent if changed
    for(Contact record: scope) {
        if(record.Phone != parents.get(record.AccountId).Phone) {
            Account updateAccount = updates.get(record.AccountId);
            if(updateAccount == null) {
                updates.put(record.AccountId, updateAccount = new Account(Id=record.AccountId));
            }
            updateAccount.Phone = record.Phone;
        }
    }
    update updates.values();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

really bad practice put query into FOR loop
please avoid this

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after update) {
    Map<Id, String> accountIdsMap = new Map<Id, String>();
    for(Contact con: Trigger.new){
        if (con.Phone != null) {
            accountIdsMap.put(con.AccountId, con.Phone);
        }
    }

    List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Phone FROM Account WHERE  Id IN :accountIdsMap.keySet() AND Phone = NULL];
    for(Account theAccount: accounts){
        theAccount.Phone = accountIdsMap.get(theAccount.Id);
    }

    update accounts;
}
```

Thanks